# Not able to create custom RetryTemplate using @StreamRetryTemplate while using multiple binders

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am using spring cloud stream with multiple binders . I tried to create custom RetryTemplate using @StreamRetryTemplate . Bean of custom RetryTempalte is being created but not injecting in AbstractBinder.
When i tried with single binder its working properly.

Version : 
Greenwich.SR1

Custom Retry Template Code Snippet

```
@StreamRetryTemplate
public RetryTemplate myRetryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    SimpleRetryPolicy simple = new SimpleRetryPolicy(4);
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simple);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

application.yml :

```
server:
  port: 7777
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      binders:
        kafka_binder:
          type: kafka
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream: 
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        input:  
          destination: EMPLOYEE-TOPIC-R1-P1
          binder: kafka_binder
          contentType: application/json
          group: so51247113
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me; open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream).

Comment: Thanks for you quick response . i have opened issue on GitHub. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1702